# Using a sum of binomials identity

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to use the following identity, taken from Henry W. Gould's combinatorial identities, [Volume 4](http://www.math.wvu.edu/~gould/Vol.4.PDF) (Equation 1.67):

$$
\sum^{n}_{k=0} \binom{x}{k}\binom{k}{n-k}2^{2k} = 2^{n}\binom{2x}{n}
$$

I have the following variant:

$$
\sum^{n}_{k=0} k\binom{x}{k}\binom{k}{n-k}2^{2k} = x\sum^{n}_{k=0} \binom{x-1}{k-1}\binom{k}{n-k}2^{2k}
$$

By absorbing $k$ into the first binomial, the lower index becomes $k-1$ and the identity no longer applies. Unfortunately, there are no other variants of this identity in Gould's list that apply to this case.

Any help or hints on how I can get the correct form is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the statement definitely correct? For n=2, I get a different coefficient of x^2 on each side.

Comment: @DominicYeo: in fact for n=1 LHS=4x≠8x=RHS

Comment: @DominicYeo: I made a mistake on the RHS of the identity (corrected now) - it is $2^n$, instead of $2^{2n}$. My apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Wilf's generating function approach:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{x-1}{k-1}2^{2k}y^k \sum_{n}\binom{k}{n-k}y^{n-k}
$$

$$
= \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{x-1}{k-1}2^{2k}y^{k}(1+y)^k 
$$

$$
= (4y+4y^{2}) \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{x-1}{k-1} (4y+4y^{2})^{k-1}
$$

Then we have the generating function

$$
g(y)=(4y+4y^{2})(1+4y+4y^{2})^{x-1}
$$

$$
= 4y(1+y)(1+2y)^{2x-2}
$$

Extract the coefficient of $y^n$

$$
[y^n]g(y)=\binom{2x}{n}\frac{2^n}{x}\bigg(n-\frac{n^{2}-n}{4x-2}\bigg)
$$

Hence

$$
x\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{x-1}{k-1}\binom{k}{n-k}2^{2k}=2^n\binom{2x}{n}\bigg(n-\frac{n^{2}-n}{4x-2}\bigg).
$$

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check/prove identities with binomial coefficients, try Petkovsek, Wilf, Zeilberger's ["A = B"](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html). Many others succumb to Wilf's "snake oil" technique (see his ["generatingfunctionology"](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html)), this is easier to do by hand.

For your sum [maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net)'s implementation of Gosper's algorithm returns that it isn't summable.